# Creating javascript/jquery object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shopping cart where I want to add elements to a cart object .

Here is how I want to do it:

=) every item has a unique id

=) **key(item id)** and **value(item quantity)**

```
=> once item is added
```

> > check if the key exists if so increment the value(by one)

> > else add a new key value pair

```
 var cart ={}
 //if id exists that_id.value +1
 //else add new key value pair
```

Comment: can you explain with your code and example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var cart = {}

function addToCart(item_id) {
  if (item_id in cart) { // Check if already in cart
    cart[item.id] += 1; // Increment
  }
  else { // Not present in cart
    cart[item_id] = 1; // Assign initial value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
var cart = {};
function addItemToCart(item) { 
    if(!cart[item.item_id]) {
        cart[item.item_id] = 0;
    }
    cart[item.item_id]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the value use it like this:

```js
 var cart ={};
 
 function addEntry(key, value, cart) {
     if (cart[key] === undefined)
         cart[key] = value;
     else
         cart[key] += value;
 }
 
 addEntry('car', 13, cart);
 addEntry('cat', 7, cart);
 addEntry('mouse', 5, cart);
 addEntry('car', 2, cart);
 addEntry('house', 1, cart);
 
 console.log(cart);
```

If only increment by one is wanted:

```js
 var cart ={};
 
 function addEntry(key, cart) {
     if (cart[key] === undefined)
         cart[key] = 1;
     else
         cart[key]++;
 }
 
 addEntry('car', cart);
 addEntry('cat', cart);
 addEntry('mouse', cart);
 addEntry('car', cart);
 addEntry('house', cart);
 
 console.log(cart);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an `addToCart` function, with 1 parameter: `item` - the item that you want to be added to the cart ( string )

```
function addToCart(item) {
    if (cart.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        cart[item]++;
    } else {
        cart[item] = 1;
    }
};
```